# bash remove substring from string

Tags: bash

I have a package name like package-0.0.1.jar and I need to remove the version information as well as the file ending .jar from this string. How can I achieve this?
I have seen that you can use the "%" sign to cut parts of a string. So I tried

```
JNAME="package-0.0.1.jar"
CLEAN="${JNAME%-.*\.jar}"
```

but this does not seem to work as CLEAN has the full JNAME content afterwards. What is the correct sequence after the % sign?

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! You really don't want to use CAPS for shell variable names. Since, [by convention](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/1081936), global environment variables are capitalized, it is bad practice to also use caps for your own, local variables because this can lead to naming collisions and hard to find bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'll try to think of it. Funny sidenote: no one of the old mighty admin guys here ever said a thing about this :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expansions with `%`/`#` do not use regexps; they use shell globs. Use just `-*.jar` to match the version and suffix.

```bash
CLEAN=${JNAME%-*.jar}
```

Bash's `[[ a =~ b ]]` and `${BASH_REMATCH[…]}` can be used if regexps become necessary (although in this case they're not):

```bash
if [[ $JNAME =~ ^(.+)-[^-]+\.jar$ ]]; then
    CLEAN=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
```

Comment: that was my mistake. Thought it would be a regex. Thanks for the hint. Works like a charm now!

Comment: +1.   Also - @roediGERhard yeah. IMO it's kind of annoying that posix sh (and bash etc) use globs for these parameter expansion options instead of regexes.  regexes are more flexible & useful (and, IMO, easier to understand. and more generally usable in other programs). Worse, instead of having just one `s/search/replace/modifiers` type operator, bash has about a dozen doing slight variations of the same thing (posix sh has about 4).  But it is what it is, and using the built-in expansions is faster than forking sed or whatever in a command-substitution sub-shell.

Answer (score 3):

One other ways is to use `awk` for this purpose (assuming the name you want end with dash)

```
CLEAN=$(printf '%s' "$JNAME" | awk -F- '{print $1}')
```

Comment: thanks for the hint, but I'd like to avoid using sed or awk here.

Comment: @roediGERhard, welcome. Just give an idea which may be applicable in other occasion :).

Comment: yes, I understood it that way too ;)

Comment: This will trip up on filenames where the package name itself includes a dash. You really want to only strip the last X components, not to keep the first 1.

Comment: @u1686_grawity, I mention this explicitly in the answer